# How to set different signer and gas payer for a single transaction

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I am trying to make a transaction of **DAI** tokens from user wallet **0xDAIUserWallet** to some random token contract say **0xRandomContractAddress**. In this scenario I am using the private key of DAI User to sign the transaction as well as to pay gas fee, as he the owner of tokens.

What I am looking for, is to sign the transaction using the DAI user private key, but the gas fee should be paid by some other wallet.

I am using standard ERC20 Ethereum smart contract designed using solidity, and using ethers.js to interact with the smart contract.

Comment: Might be useful https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender